# where is torch.tensor.item() defined at the Github?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I am torch Newbie.

when I was learning torch tutorial like below,
I was curious about **where tensor.item() is defined**.

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1])
print( a.item() )  # it works without problem.
```

In order to find what i dont know,

**First**, I used VScode. but I got this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z2BZ.png)
not like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbSdG.png)

**Second**, I searched "def item()" at [the torch Github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/torch)
But, I could not find. T^T

Could you tell me where [tensor.item()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.item) is defined at [the Github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/torch)?

Or

where [Class_torch.tensor's Menber functions(Method function)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) are defined??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

[torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable_indexing.cpp:268](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/46cf6d332f075ed90d3baf21c32de51e4f304549/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable_indexing.cpp#L268)

**Long answer:**

I hope you like C++. ;)

The first thing to know is that `item()` isn't (usually) a method in most Python classes. Instead, Python converts calls to `item()` into other underlying methods like `__getitem__()` as a convenience. Knowing that:

`class Tensor` is defined at [torch/tensor.py:40](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/46cf6d332f075ed90d3baf21c32de51e4f304549/torch/tensor.py#L40).

Most of Torch's underlying, compute intensive functionality is implemented in C and C++, including `Tensor`. "class Tensor" is based on `Torch._C.TensorBase` which is provided to Python via a C API from [torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp:812](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/46cf6d332f075ed90d3baf21c32de51e4f304549/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp#L812)

`THPVariableType` is a map given to Python describing the C++ functions available on the object from Python. It's defined at [torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/46cf6d332f075ed90d3baf21c32de51e4f304549/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp#L739). The part relevant to you is the `tp_as_mapping` entry (line 752), which provides functions for objects implementing the mapping protocol - basically Pyton Array-like objects ([Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html))

The `THPVariable_as_mapping` structure at line 725 provides the mapping methods.The second variable provides the a subscript function used to get items by index ([Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyMappingMethods.mp_subscript))

Therefore, The C++ function `TPHVariable_getitem` provides the implementation of `Torch.Tensor.item()`, and it is defined at [torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable_indexing](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/22a34bcf4e5eaa348f0117c414c3dd760ec64b13/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable_indexing.cpp#L268)

Comment: thanks. I fully understand.I like C++! ;)

Comment: Can you please provide links to documentation for the `item` behavior you describe? It sounds similar to the behavior of `iter` and related functions, but I haven't found official docs for `item`.

Comment: `Instead, Python converts calls to item() into other underlying methods like __getitem__() as a convenience.` this suggests that there is some automatism but I think the method `item` is just called `item` and there is nothing special about it.